# Why data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want to fix my buttons when I am scrolling my content .I used this `data-position="fixed"` `data-tap-toggle="false"`. But it does not work, buttons also scroll up.
When I used position absolute it comes bottom.So I used position relative .If I add these button with header, then the background blue them display back on buttons.
Can you please suggest another way so that buttons will be fixed when I scroll the content.

I click the button it show buttons and text field .Then scroll my contend buttons also scroll .
Here is my fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/E65Uy/

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {

   $("#searchbar").toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: You don't want the button on the blue top bar?

Comment: No ..you understand wrong

Comment: I need button should come above text..

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by disabling CSS animations..

```
.slidedown, .reverse, .out {
    -o-transition-property: none !important;
    -moz-transition-property: none !important;
    -ms-transition-property: none !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: none !important;
    transition-property: none !important;
    -o-transform: none !important;
    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    -moz-animation: none !important;
    -o-animation: none !important;
    -ms-animation: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"
```

are used for data-role="header" tags not for other divs or elements

Refer this, http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

You should use css style attribute position to make other elements fixed

Comment: css attributes like position: fixed

Comment: The buttons are fixed while scrolling in the example. That's what u want right?

Comment: @Rohit http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/E65Uy/10/ working for me, just don't have a background

Comment: but button come above the text.I don't need this ..Button should come up then text

Answer (score 0):

I have made a change to your fiddle.

I changed this line: `<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" style='z-index:9999'>`

**EDIT:**

I have changed the fiddle, is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/E65Uy/11/

Comment: But buttons also scroll ?

Comment: You don't want the buttons which appear later also to scroll?

Comment: yes..Mean if I used click button .It show buttons.Then they should not scroll

Comment: Just add the buttons to the header `div` itself.