# How to replace space to underscore at same time (when i enter the text in input field)?

Tags: jquery, regex

can you please tell me how to replace space to underscore at same time (when i enter the text in input field)?
If I have string I used like that.

```
replace(/ /g,"_");
```

But I am looking for when user enter text on input field then It automatically replace the space with underscore .I used keyup event it only fire first time.

```
$("#test").keyup(function() {
  var textValue = $(this).val();
    if(textValue==' '){
        alert("hh");
    }
});
```

Comment: first of all better use keydown.

Comment: i in a similar situation placed it in the html as "onKeyDown = 'foo();'"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AEB6N/)

```
$("#test").keyup(function () {
    var textValue = $(this).val();
    textValue =textValue.replace(/ /g,"_");
    $(this).val(textValue);
});
```

**Update**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AEB6N/4)

```
$("#test").keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g, "_");
});
```

Comment: This is an overall better approach than testing which key was pressed.  The overhead is minimal

Comment: can any body solve my this problem also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502449/why-data-position-fixed-data-tap-toggle-false-not-work/18502566?noredirect=1#comment27204600_18502566

Comment: @tushar please check this question also solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502449/why-data-position-fixed-data-tap-toggle-false-not-work/18502566?noredirect=1#comment27204600_18502566

Comment: @Rohit can't help you with that question.I don't know jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Simply try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92y3x/)

```
$("#test").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().match(/[ ]/g, "") != null) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[ ]/g, "_"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/JweXf/)**

code

```
$("#test").keyup(function(e) {
  (/ /i).test(this.value)?this.value = this.value.replace(/ /ig,'_'):null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect which key was pressed by adding an argument to your callback (say `e`) then testing it's `which` property (from [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/))

```
$("#test").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 32 /*space*/){
        alert("hh");
    }
});
```

Comment: please help to solve this questionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502449/why-data-position-fixed-data-tap-toggle-false-not-work/18502566?noredirect=1#comment27204600_18502566

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the whole value in the event with a .split(' ').join('_'); 
It is faster than a replace.

so,

```
$("#test").keyup(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().split(' ').join('_'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test").keypress(function(e) {
  var textValue = $(this).val();
    if(e.keyCode === 32){
        $("#test").val(textValue + "_");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: please help in this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502449/why-data-position-fixed-data-tap-toggle-false-not-work/18502566?noredirect=1#comment27204600_18502566

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FTmg9/

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').keydown(function(){
         $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, "_"));
    });
});
```